# python - how to create if-else condition for getting max values in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I am a beginner for using python and i would like to know how to compare the value in pandas.

in this case, im trying to compare values in each row with the max values and then drop it out.

for example, i have the matrix as df

```
   x1  x2 x3   max
x1 1   3  3     3
x2 0.5 1  0.25  1
x3 6   7  8     8
```

i have tried my code like this but it is not working and get `KeyError: 0`

```
 for i in range(len(df)):
     for j in range(len(df)-1):
        if df[j].values.equal(df.max(axis=1)):
          print('max', jac_sim[j])
```

my expected output is to get the pair of a data frame in the first row such as

```
Max (x1,x2), (x1,x3)
```

Comment: what's your for loop doing?

Comment: first loop is to get the row values and the second loop is to get the value in each column. after that trying to compare the value in each row with max value. if it finds, return the pair of data.

Comment: If it finds what?

Comment: I would like to know which pairs of data have the max value. if it finds, get the pairs

Comment: do you mean which columns equals the max value column?

Comment: yes, i mean that. sorry for my english

Comment: It's still not clear. I see that you've edited your question. Do you want a dataframe as your output or do you just want to print your output?

Comment: You can compare different columns for equality using `df['x1'].eq(df['max'])`. It will return a Boolean series where corresponding indices will indicate if the values are equal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would rewrite the code like this (more readable):

```
# Create a sample dataframe
data = [(1  , 3,  3   ,  3), 
        (0.5, 1,  0.25,  1), 
        (6  , 7,  8   ,  8)]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, 
                  columns=['x1', 'x2', 'x3', 'max'],
                  index  =['x1', 'x2', 'x3'])
print(df)

# Your code could be rewriten like the following
col_names = df.columns.values
row_names = df.index
for row, cols in df.iterrows():
    max = cols['max']
    other_cols = cols.drop('max')
    print("Max", end =" ")
    for col in range(len(other_cols)):
        if other_cols[col] == max:
            print('(', row, ',', col_names[col], ')', end =" ")
    print()
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: thank you for your help, i have followed to your rewrite and found the key error problem like this ' KeyError   ----> 8         if other_cols[col] == max_value: '. i have no idea about to create the if-else with pandas T T

Comment: I see. Maybe because I didn't consider that your row indices are names rather that integers. I have updated my answer with a sample dataframe that reproduces yours.

Comment: got it! and it's working well. thank you for your help T T. by the way, i would like to ask one more question. is it possible to print only the first result. i have tried to remove for loop, but it gets the last result. thank you in advance.

Comment: To do that, you can simply replace the last `print()` by `break`